# Creating a Macro that Copies over Values from One Sheet to Another Based on a Key

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am trying to create a genera-table template in Excel. Eventually, I would like to be able to generate a template from a list of staff and tasks with any number of weeks in the rotation based on a Key.

So, when you hit generate if the key says one week then you would get each staff members name copied over into one row of the template sheet. However, if the key said 5 week, then it would copy each name 5 times in the Template sheet.

So, you would have a column with each staff's name listed 5 times and the next staff's name would be 5 times.

Below is the general shell that I have created in the hopes of achieving this. My question is two parts

1. Is this a reasonable method to achieve what I want
2. If this is a reasonable method then how would I actually tell it to copy the information from the staff sheet and paste it into the template sheet x number of times based on a Key cell which would say 1 week, 5 week, etc.

```
Sub Gernerate_Template()
For Each cell In Worksheets("Staff").Range("A:A")
    If Worksheets("Template").Range("D1") = "1 Week" Then    
        Worksheets("Staff").Range("A1").Copy
        Worksheets("Template").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 
        If Worksheets("Template").Range("D1") = "5 Week" Then    
            Worksheets("Staff").Range("A1").Copy
            Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:A5").PasteSpecial

            Exit For

Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, this should do what you want.

I'm assuming your value in D4 will always be "x Week"

I'm starting both sheets at row 1 since you don't appear to have a header row.

```
Sub populate_Template()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim repetition As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    With Sheets("Staff")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))
        repetition = Split(.Cells(1, 4).Value, " ")(0)
    End With
    
    Dim newarr() As String
    ReDim newarr(1 To lr * repetition, 1 To 1)
    With Sheets("Template")
        count = 0
        For i = 1 To lr
            For y = 1 To repetition
                count = count + 1
                newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)
            Next y
        Next i
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(count, 1)).Value = newarr
    End With
End Sub
```

Tested on 10,000 names repeated 10 times each takes about .6 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for the help! When I tried to run this code I got a subscript out of range error for this line: repetition = Split(.Cells(1, 4).Value, " ")(0). However, when I googled the error it normally has something to do with an element missing but I don't know what element that would be here? I currently have cell D1 filled with 5 Week

Comment: I got it working! Now, I am trying to move this proof of concept to my actual excel file where things don't start on column A row 1. Now the staff listing starts on D9 and the Template sheet needs the info to go to cell B6. I get that I need to adjust the cell references in the code. For example I updated the repetition cell to (2,3) as in the actual sheet it is in cell C2. However, I am getting a type mismatch for " newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)" what do I do there?

Comment: What is the value in `arr(i, 1)` when it throws that error?

Comment: I just needed to update that cell reference too. It is working now! Thank you!!!